# How to log all queries sent to SQL Server from the client side?

Tags: sql-server, logging

I'm aware SQL Profiler will tell you everything you need to know about queries going on at the server side. But, can you do something similar to log queries from the client side in the SQL Native Client?

This would be helpful for tracing failing SQL statements that originate from third party assemblies, where it's not possible to step through code, in an environment where profiler access is relegated only to busy DBAs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SqlExpressProfiler. It has worked well for me.

http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler

Comment: That's just the SQL Profiler for the Express editions - that's not really what the OP is looking for.....

Comment: OP says they don't have access to the profiler - this is an alternate way of getting that.